# How to Get Items from the specific folder with specific TemplateName in Parameters

Tags: powershell-extensions

How to get the **items** with specific template only. I need this, beacuse it is useful for the **bucketable** items, like Tags

**Here is my code:**

```
$props = @{
    Title = "Test"
    Description = "Test"
    OkButtonName = "Run Report"
    CancelButtonName = "Cancel"
    Parameters = @(
        @{ Name = "TagName"; Title = "Tag Name"; Editor = "multilist"; Source = "/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/" }
        @{ Title = "Note"; Value = "SitecoreExchange"; Editor = "info" }
    )
}
```

**Here is the path (where I want specific template):**

```
Source = "/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore PowerShell has a report to get items by a specific ID:

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Lists all content items that inherit from a given template
        
    .NOTES
        Alex Washtell
#>

$database = "master"
$root = Get-Item -Path (@{$true="$($database):\content\home"; $false="$($database):\content"}[(Test-Path -Path "$($database):\content\home")])
$baseTemplate = Get-Item master:\templates

$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
        @{Name="root"; Title="Choose the report root"; Tooltip="Only items from this root will be returned."; }
        @{ Name = "baseTemplate"; Title="Base Template"; Tooltip="Select the item to use as a base template for the report"; Root="/sitecore/templates/"}
    )
    Title = "Items With Template Report"
    Description = "Choose the criteria for the report."
    Width = 550
    Height = 300
    ShowHints = $true
    Icon = [regex]::Replace($PSScript.Appearance.Icon, "Office", "OfficeWhite", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)
}

$result = Read-Variable @props

if($result -eq "cancel") {
    exit
}

filter Where-InheritsTemplate {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]$item
    )
    
    if ($item) {
        $itemTemplate = [Sitecore.Data.Managers.TemplateManager]::GetTemplate($item)

        if ($itemTemplate.DescendsFromOrEquals($baseTemplate.ID)) {
            $Item
        }
    }
}

$items = @($root) + @(($root.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item)) | Where-InheritsTemplate

if($items.Count -eq 0) {
    Show-Alert "There are no content items that inherit from this template"
} else {
    $props = @{
        Title = "Item Template Report"
        InfoTitle = "Items that inherit from the '$($baseTemplate.Name)' template"
        InfoDescription = "The following items all inherit from the '$($baseTemplate.FullPath)' template."
        PageSize = 25
    }
    
    $items |
        Show-ListView @props -Property @{Label="Icon"; Expression={$_.__Icon} },
            @{Label="Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName} },
            @{Label="Updated"; Expression={$_.__Updated} },
            @{Label="Updated by"; Expression={$_."__Updated by"} },
            @{Label="Created"; Expression={$_.__Created} },
            @{Label="Created by"; Expression={$_."__Created by"} },
            @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.ItemPath} }
}

Close-Window
```

Comment: @VladLobagiu Thank you, but this does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the items with a specific template only via template ID:

```
$allItem = Get-ChildItem -Path $itemPath -Recurse | where-object 
{$_.TemplateID -eq "{1D5C266A-112F-4EA2-A69E-E4865ACE2200}"}
```

Here in `$itemPath` you can assign the root path and it will return you all child items with specified TemplateId.

You can update condition like instead of `TemplateId` you want to search with `TemplateName` then update code:

```
$_.TemplateName -eq "TemplateName"
```

If you want to get items on the basis of `Field value` then:

```
$_.Fields["FieldName"].Value
```

You can use `Find-Item` command as well.

Comment: I know about this, thank you for answering. Still my question is how to get this in `Source` field lets say, in `Parameters`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by just adding the `/*/*/*/*/*` at the end of the **Source** in **Parameters** Object.

```
$props = @{
    Title = "Get All Media Items by Tag"
    Description = "Get all Media items by Tag"
    OkButtonName = "Run Report"
    CancelButtonName = "Cancel"
    Parameters = @(  
        @{ Name = "TagName"; Title = "Tag Name"; Editor = "multilist"; Source = "/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/*/*/*/*/*"}
        @{ Title = "Note"; Value = "Select Tags you need for the Images from the Tag Repository"; Editor = "info" }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the template query in your source like this : `/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/[@@templatename='TagTemplateName']`

and don’t forget to replace the *TagTemplateName* with the name of the template you want to filter.

working code

```
 $props = @{
    Title = "Test"
    Description = "Test"
    OkButtonName = "Run Report"
    CancelButtonName = "Cancel"
    Parameters = @(
        @{ Name = "TagName"; Title = "Tag Name"; Editor = "multilist"; Source = "/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository/[@@templatename='TagTemplateName']" }
        @{ Title = "Note"; Value = "SitecoreExchange"; Editor = "info" }
    )
}
```